# VBA-carriage returns

Tags: vba, excel, line-breaks, carriage-return

new here, and in VBA in general. I have created a macro that copies the contents of a cell in excel and pastes in a specific location in a word document. FYI, i use bookmarks in word to select the exact location for pasting. the issue is that everything copied inserts a line and/or paragraph/carriage return. i have found a lot of possible solutions but none of them work, prob given my inexperience in VBA. Please help!

```
Sub OpenWord()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim R1 As Object
    Dim R2 As Object

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\KG\Desktop\VBA WIP\FAfile.docx")
    Set R1 = WordDoc.Bookmarks("b1")
    Set R2 = WordDoc.Bookmarks("b2")

        WordApp.Visible = True
        WordApp.Activate

            Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H4").copy
            R1.Select
            WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis
            Application.CutCopyMode = True

            Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H7").copy
            R2.Select
            WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis
            Application.CutCopyMode = True


    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set R1 = Nothing
    Set R2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues here.

At first since you are using late binding `CreateObject("Word.Application")` you probably not have included references to `Microsoft Word ... Object Library`. But then the constant [wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/wdrecoverytype-enumeration-word) will not be set and be 0. Using late binding the constant names cannot be used. The appropriate values must be used instead.

And using [Selection.PasteAndFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/selection-pasteandformat-method-word) you are pasting the whole table cell instead of only the value. As of your description you wants only pasting the value.

To pasting the value only try [Selection.PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-pastespecial-method-word):

```
...
            Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H4").Copy
            R1.Select
            'WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:= 20
            WordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H7").Copy
            R2.Select
            'WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:= 20
            WordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
...
```

Where the 2 is the value of [wdPasteText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdpastedatatype-enumeration-word).

If formatted content will be needed from Excel, then do using [wdPasteRTF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdpastedatatype-enumeration-word) instead, which is 1 instead of 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following method, instead. As for Excel, when working with Word's object model it's better to use the underlying objects, rather than selecting. And it's also better to avoid using the Clipboard unless you absolutely need to. Word also has a `Range` object, which is a useful "target".

Note that this approach will lose any formatting in the Excel sheet.

If you want to bring across formatting, using the code in your question, then you will be bringing in the *worksheet structure* at the same time: you'll be pasting a table cell. That may be what you think is a new line/paragraph. The variation I include (see the three ''') pastes just the font formatting, without the Excel structures (equivalent to PasteSpecial as RTF in the UI).

```
Sub OpenWord()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim R1 As Object
    Dim R2 As Object

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\KG\Desktop\VBA WIP\FAfile.docx")
    Set R1 = WordDoc.Bookmarks("b1").Range
    Set R2 = WordDoc.Bookmarks("b2").Range

        WordApp.Visible = True
        'Put it at the end, before "clean up" if you want to do this
        'WordApp.Activate

    R1.Text = Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H4").Text
    R2.Text = Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H7").Text

    '''Sheets("Details INPUT").Range("H7").copy
    '''R2.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
    'CutCopyMode is NOT boolean, pass it either 1 or 0 or the xl-constant value!
    '''Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy

    Set R1 = Nothing
    Set R2 = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Good approach for only setting the values from Excel into bookmark ranges.